# three finger tap not working with synaptics touchpad driver

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Unity and I have heard that there should be system gestures enabled by default. Two finger scrolling is working well, however three finger gestures are not. Here is xinput:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (143):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (268): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (272):  1576, 5366, 1353, 4499
Synaptics Finger (273): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (274):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (275):   251
Synaptics Tap Durations (276):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (277):   0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (278):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (279):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (280):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (281): -114, -114
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (282): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (283):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (284): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.034934, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (285):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (286):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (287):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (288): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (289):   1, 1, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (290): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (291):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (292): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (293):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (294): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (295):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (296): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (297):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (298): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (299):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (300):  0
Synaptics Gestures (301):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (302):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (303): 68, 44
Synaptics Area (304):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (305): 8, 8
Device Product ID (262):    2, 7
Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

And here is synclient:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1576
RightEdge               = 5366
TopEdge                 = 1353
BottomEdge              = 4499
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 251
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = -114
HorizScrollDelta        = -114
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0349345
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 8
VertHysteresis          = 8
ClickPad                = 0
```

Kernel version

```
3.19.0-49-generic
```

Am I missing something simple or something is really wrong here?

Comment: What do you want to do on a 3-finger tap?

Comment: @Pilot6 all things listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch)

Comment: Unity does not support all that, you can set 3-finger tap for a middle mouse button. That wiki is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 So I am left with touchegg only?

Comment: Most likely it is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Should work in any device with "synclient". Just run:

"synclient TapButton3=2"

this sets the middle finger button to the gesture action configured, namely paste the selected test.

Comment: Yes it works on Ubuntu 20.10,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using xubuntu 16.04

From your synclient

TapButton1              = 1 ;;;; Left Button One Finger
TapButton2              = 3 ;;;; Right Button Two Fingers
TapButton3              = 0 ;;;; No Button asigned Three Fingers

I use 1 Finger Left Button(1) 2 Fingers Middle (2) 3 Fingers Right (3)

But right now my touchpad confuses sometimes two and three fingers.

Hope it helps.